# Substituting a Python class method for a mock method

Tags: python, mocking, magicmock

I have a question similar to the questions posted here, which also have no satisfying answer yet: 
[mocking a method with another reusable method with arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090104/mocking-a-method-with-another-reusable-method-with-arguments-in-python) 
[Using mock patch to mock an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469680/using-mock-patch-to-mock-a-class-method)

I have the following Production class and UnitTest class. In the second test case in the UnitTest class, I want to substitute the real method for the fake method, which I have defined above the Unit Test class. However, I am unable to connect the method `even_numbers` in the system under test to the fake method `odd_numbers`, including its input arguments. How should this substition look like? I am using Python 2.7.

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class ProdClass(object):        
    def even_numbers(self, numbers):
        print 'This is the real method'
        return [n for n in numbers if n%2 == 0]

def odd_numbers(numbers):
    print 'This is the mock'
    return [n for n in numbers if n%2 != 0]

class MockingTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_even_numbers_01(self):
        sut = ProdClass()        

        result = sut.even_numbers(range(10))
        expected_result = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result,  
                         msg = '\nRetrieved: \n{0}\nExpected: \n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))

    @patch('ProdClass.even_numbers') 
    def test_even_numbers_02(self, mock_even_numbers):
        sut = ProdClass()
        '''Substitute real method even_numbers with mocked method even_numbers here'''
        mock_even_numbers.return_value = odd_numbers

        result = sut.even_numbers(range(10))
        expected_result = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved: \n{0}\nExpected: \n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**EDIT**: With the help of Martijn below, I have edited the code into this working example:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

class ProdClass(object):

    def even_numbers(self, numbers):
        print 'This is the real method'
        return [n for n in numbers if n%2 == 0]

def odd_numbers(numbers):
    print 'This is the mock'
    return [n for n in numbers if n%2 != 0]

class MockingTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_even_numbers_01(self):
        sut = ProdClass()        

        result = sut.even_numbers(range(10))
        expected_result = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result,  
                         msg = '\nRetrieved: \n{0}\nExpected: \n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))

    @patch.object(ProdClass, 'even_numbers') 
    def test_even_numbers_02(self, mock_even_numbers):
        sut = ProdClass()
        '''Substitute real method even_numbers with mocked method even_numbers here'''
        mock_even_numbers.side_effect = odd_numbers

        result = sut.even_numbers(range(10))
        expected_result = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result, 
                         msg = '\nRetrieved: \n{0}\nExpected: \n{1}'.format(result, expected_result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You did not read the second post you linked to properly. They use `patch.object()` there, not `patch()`. `@patch.object(ProdClass, 'even_numbers')` would do what you wanted.

Comment: I still don't understand how to use it. If I add `@patch.object(ProdClass, 'even_numbers')` to the top of the test method, and keep the rest the same, the return value (stored in `result`) is an instance of the function `odd_numbers`, not the return value of that function. How should I *call* that function `odd_numbers` with the proper argument?

Comment: `return_value` is what calling `even_numbers` returns when called, yes. It sounds like you wanted to use `side_effect` instead.

Comment: That indeed does exactly what I want it to do, thanks! I find the name `side_effects` misleading though. Is there a reason it is called side effects, while you're actually changing the entire implementation?

Comment: Mocking is not usually about changing the implementation; you usually just produce a *static* return value. `side_effect` is for the complex situations, like raising an exception, or handling multiple calls where the static value returned depends on more complex determinations from the arguments.